# Краш приложения на Android - Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Здравствуйте!

Проблема в том, что приложение крашится, если не сайт недоступен.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_rss_tabs);

    // Then get the TabHost
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    /* *****************
     * First tab
     */ 
    Intent FirstIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
    // Set First category RSS URL
    FirstIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://gov.tuva.ru/rss_mainnews.php");
    // The name of the First tab taken from the String resources

    String FirstTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_1);
    TabSpec FirstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(FirstTabName)
                                .setIndicator(FirstTabName, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_1))
                                .setContent(FirstIntent);
    // Add First tab to the TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(FirstTabSpec);
```

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Не завидую правительству Тувы ))

Answer (score 1):

Для начала обработать эту ситуацию и вынести сетевые операции из главного потока, иначе будет падать на старших версиях

---

google рекомендует выносить работу с сетью в отдельный сервис, это хорошо правильно ... но иногда удобнее  AsyncTask, он имеет свои проблемы при повороте экранна теряет ссылку на activity, но это лечится [AsyncTask. Поворот экрана](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/154-urok-91-asynctask-povorot-ekrana)

Comment: Можно пример кода, пожалуйста?

Comment: Ловить исключения в блоке try/catch  про это в люом случае придется почитать, есть разные варианты реализации работы с сетью, самый простой работа в  AsyncTask не совсем корректно